# SVG doesn't work on subdomain - some browsers try to download rather than display

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, cross-browser, subdomain

I have a site with a 'development' subdomain, which displays my SVG file exactly as intended.

However when I copy it across to www, or any other subdomain (e.g. 'test') some browsers try to open the file in an external editor, therefore asking me to download the file rather than displaying it.

For example:

- http://development.mysite.com/test.svg - works
- http://www.mysite.com/test.svg - doesn't work

The SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

This happens in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, **however IE9 and above display the file as intended**.

It is a Windows hosting, but I'm not using a web.config file on either subdomain.

My hunch is that there must be some setting on the server which I need my hosting company to make.  Can anyone suggest what might cause this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG files need to be served with a valid mime type, the most usual is image/svg+xml. I guess you are most likely serving the file as text/plain.

This is a server issue, but how you configure the mime type for a file depends on the specifics of the server or hosting environment.

Comment: Can the mime type be set differently for subdomains on the same server?

Comment: Sure, one way would be to use a different server to serve subdomains.